# MySQL Wordpress database Unknown column in where clause error

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I know this has been asked a bunch of times and I looked through some posts but couldn't find anything solution for my problem. Not sure how to break this down if someone could help me understand what the issue is.

I am getting a lot of `WP DB error unknown column in 'where clause' for query SELECT`. Trying to understand the error it seems to stem from my woocommerce product names or my W3 total cache plugin?

Error 1:

> WordPress database error Unknown column 'tter.name' in 'where clause'
>   for query SELECT   xxx_posts.ID FROM xxx_posts  INNER JOIN
>   xxx_postmeta ON ( xxx_posts.ID = xxx_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND
>   (((((xxx_posts.post_title LIKE '%journals%') OR
>   (xxx_posts.post_content LIKE '%journals%'))) OR ((tter.name LIKE
>   '%journals%'))  OR ((tter.slug LIKE '%journals%'))  OR
>   ((ttax.description LIKE '%journals%')) ))  AND
>   (xxx_posts.post_password = '')  AND ( 
>         ( xxx_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(xxx_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','search') )
>       ) AND xxx_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((xxx_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY xxx_posts.ID ORDER BY xxx_posts.post_date DESC  made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main,
>   do_action_ref_array, call_user_func_array,
>   WC_Query->get_products_in_view, get_posts, WP_Query->query,
>   WP_Query->get_posts, W3_Db->query, W3_DbCache->query,
>   W3_DbCallUnderlying->query, W3_Db->query, W3_DbProcessor->query,
>   W3_Db->default_query

Error 2:

> WordPress database error Unknown column 'tter.name' in 'where clause'
>   for query SELECT   xxx_posts.ID FROM xxx_posts  INNER JOIN
>   xxx_postmeta ON ( xxx_posts.ID = xxx_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND
>   (((((xxx_posts.post_title LIKE '%Banks%') OR (xxx_posts.post_content
>   LIKE '%Banks%'))) OR ((tter.name LIKE '%Banks%'))  OR ((tter.slug LIKE
>   '%banks%'))  OR ((ttax.description LIKE '%Banks%')) ))  AND
>   (xxx_posts.post_password = '')  AND ( 
>         ( xxx_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(xxx_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','search') )
>       ) AND xxx_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((xxx_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY xxx_posts.ID ORDER BY xxx_posts.post_date DESC  made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main,
>   do_action_ref_array, call_user_func_array,
>   WC_Query->get_products_in_view, get_posts, WP_Query->query,
>   WP_Query->get_posts, W3_Db->query, W3_DbCache->query,
>   W3_DbCallUnderlying->query, W3_Db->query, W3_DbProcessor->query,
>   W3_Db->default_query

Comment: `tter` should be `xxx_postmeta`

Comment: How/where do I change that?

Comment: No it shouldn't. The WordPress `postmeta` table doesn't have a `name` column (unless something's changed recently).  I suspect it's trying to query the `terms` table (probably `xxx_terms` in your setup). It looks like a filter's adding that condition where it shouldn't, or failing to add a join to the `terms` table.  I'd take a copy of your site, turn off all plugins, revert to the default theme, then reactivate them one by one (theme first, then plugins) until you can narrow down where the problem is coming from. Once you know that, you can refine your question (or do a more targeted search).

Comment: @Hobo since I am only registering this error in my error_log file, how do you suggest I find it in real time once I reactive a plugin to see if its the cause of the issue?

Comment: If it were me, I'd make a local copy of the site, and start by using your site's search functionality to see if that reproduces the problem.  I'm just guessing by the content of the SQL, but it looks like someone's searching for the word `journals` (error 1) or `banks` (error 2).  Once I've got a way of reproducing the problem, I'd go with the theme and plugin investigation I mentioned before. I don't know your site, so can't give specific advice.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try searching your site's PHP files for the string `ttax.description LIKE`, which might help track it down.

Comment: @Hobo Okay, thanks for the help, I will try those out.

Comment: @Hobo Found the issue within one of the plugins; searching for that term helped. Thanks again.

Comment: Great news.  Glad to help.